# Jekyll UTF-8 Front Matter Issue with Github Pages

Tags: utf-8, jekyll, github-pages

### Scenario:

I have a variable within the front matter of every blog post which looks like the following:

```
---
icon: &#9749;
---
```

When I display a list of blog posts I reference this UTF-8 character

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  <span class="icon">{{ post.icon }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

I build the site locally, check localhost:4000 to make sure everything is fine, and then push to GitHub. My site is hosted by GitHub Pages and GitHub will build the site every time I push to master.

### Problem:

The site looks fine when I build it locally. I can see the UTF-8 character displayed and when I check the source of the page it shows a span tag with the UTF-8 character.

```
<span class="icon">&#9749;</span>
```

However, the UTF-8 character is **not visible** on the website built by GitHub and the UTF-8 character **is not** within the span tag

```
<span class="icon"></span>
```

I have double checked and made sure that I have pushed everything to origin. Why is my UTF-8 character missing?

**EDIT:** I have solved my problem but I still do not know *why* it was happening. I think knowing why GitHub is failing to properly parse the front-matter is worth knowing and I will keep this question open until someone is able to find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem I needed to surround my front-matter UTF-8 characters in quotes:

```
---
icon: "&#9749;"
---
```

I also had to enclose every other front-matter variable in quotes, despite not needing to before adding the icon variable.

```
---
layout: "default"
icon: "&#9749;"
---
```

I am still not certain why the unquoted UTF-8 character will work locally but not for GutHub.